# LaunchImages XCode 5

Tags: catalog, assets, launchimage

I declared the LaunchImages and icons but there were errors when validating the archive. So I used the asset catalogs and the errors disappeared. as far as good but the app does not show any LaunchImage when running it on my iPhone 4S.

What might be the problem?